# Config Transformation Tool can't find AppHarbor.TransformTester assembly

Tags: .net, web.config-transform

I'm trying out the [Config Transformation Tester](https://ctt.codeplex.com/) tool. The download provided is a single file called `ctt.exe`. When I run it as follows:

```
ctt s:Web.config t:Web.Debug.config d:Web.Out.config
```

...I get the following output:

> Exception Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlNodeException: Could not load
>   file or as sembly 'AppHarbor.TransformTester' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot  find the file specified. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load f ile or assembly
>   'AppHarbor.TransformTester' or one of its dependencies. The syst em
>   cannot find the file specified.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   cod eBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntro spection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   as semblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMar k& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIn trospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evid ence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolea n forIntrospection)
>   ...

Clearly, it's expecting to find some `AppHarbor.TransformTester.dll` and can't find it. But neither can I. Where do I get this assembly?

Alternatively, is there a better command-line tool available which can be used to apply Web/app.config transformations and be used as part of an automated build process?

**Update**: I get this even when compiling from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was me doing something stupid.

I took the sample configs from the [config transformation tester](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/). The sample Web.Debug.config there includes a reference to AppHarbor.TransformTester:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <xdt:Import assembly="AppHarbor.TransformTester" namespace="AppHarbor.TransformTester.Transforms"/>

  <configSections xdt:Transform="MergeBefore(/configuration/*)" />

  <configSections>
    <section name="mySection" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Merge" />

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="bar" connectionString="value" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      </customErrors>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Just use a proper config instead and you'll be fine.